# Is there a Sefer that explains each 'melech' in the megilla?

Tags: jewish-books, commentaries, midrash, megillat-esther

Esther Rabba (3:10) says that any place in the megilla where it says מלך without specifying אחשוורוש afterwards, it is referring to both the mundane king - Achashverosh, and to the holy king - hashem. (The gemara brings a similar d'rasha, but only about a single passuk).

Is there any Sefer/ peirush that, based on this midrash, explains for each מלך mentioned in the megilla how to understand it to mean hashem? (There are many Pessukim where just saying "it refers to hashem" doesn't make sense without further explanation.)